# Вызов метода одного потока из другого

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qtcreator

У меня есть функция которая вызывается отдельным потоком и поток отделяется:

```
 std::thread thr(IncrementTime:: incTime);
 thr.detach();
```

Эта функция представляет собой бесконечный цикл.

**Задача стоит в том, чтобы изменять  label формы(Widget) после каждого прохождения цикла.**

Части кода:

IncrementTime.h

```
#ifndef INCREMENTTIME_H
#define INCREMENTTIME_H

class IncrementTime
{
public:
    static void incTime();
};

#endif // INCREMENTTIME_H
```

IncrementTime.cpp

```
#include "incrementtime.h"
#include "global_objects.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "widget.h"

void IncrementTime::incTime(){
    Widget widg;
    while(1){
        sec++;
        if(sec == 60){
            sec = 0;
        }
          //тут выпадает ошибка
        widg.smena(); //Cannot create children for a parent that is in a 
        Sleep(1000); //different thread
    }
}
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include "global_objects.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Widget::smena(){
        ui->label_3->setText(QString::number(sec));
}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    void smena();

private:
Ui::Widget *ui;

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

Comment: в Qt есть встроенные таймеры - `QTimer`. Вы можете его запустить (указав таймаут в одну секунду), и по сигналу от таймера вызывать слот в вашем виджете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работать с GUI можно только из основного потока программы. В вашем случае поток должен не сам изменять значения на виджете, а отправлять ему сигнал для изменения данных, чтобы все изменения происходили в главном потоке.
Отдельный поток нужен, если вычисления требуют много времени и интерфейс постоянно зависает, но если в вашем incTime() нет ничего другого, то логичнее использовать таймер и не заморачиваться с потоками.